# place graphics inside tikzpicture and minipage

Tags: floats, positioning

I have made this structure to create title of my poster, with logo

```
\newcommand{\displaytitle}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
      \begin{minipage}{0.98\textwidth}
        \centering
        \Title{#1}\\%\vspace{1.cm}
        \begin{tabular}{l C{0.79\textwidth}l}
          \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.06\textwidth]{uu.png}}&
          \LARGE\color{pms187}{#2}&
          \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.06\textwidth]{mca.jpg}}\\
          &\large\color{pms187}{$^\ast$myemail@foo.com}&\\\vspace{.1cm}\\
          &\Large\color{pms187}{#3}&\\
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{-1cm}
      \end{minipage}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This works fine, when the title is 1 line. If title is more than 1 line, the logos (uu.png and mca.png) overflows the `tikzpicuture` box.

One work around, which I am following is to make those pictures smaller(As shown in the picture).
The other is, and what I want is to place the pictures higher (just below the first line of the title).
How I can do that? 
[image: Screenshot of the displaytitle]

Comment: A complete MWE (which includes the definitions of mybox and C) would be useful.

Comment: If C{} is like p{} only centered, then you can add the title to the tabular and it will only count as one more row.  (Also include the definition of \Title.)